# Selenium scraping with HTML changing after refresh

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using Selenium along with python to scrape some pages. I have many web pages that represent the same type of objects(football player information) but each of them has a slightly different HTML layout. In particular my main issue here is that  the div class identifiers change when refreshing or changing web page, in a way which is unpredictable.

[image]

In the specific case I would like to get the data in the div which class identifier "jss176", but when I get to another player this will change to "jss450" for example, with no meaningful pattern to be found.
Is there a way I can go around this? I was thinking of navigating through the Childs starting from div with id = "root", but I don't seem to find a good piece of code to achieve this.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If only the id's change, but not the web structure, you could scrape the info by XPATH.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-xpath-in-selenium-with-python

You can directly access the div you want and select in chrome "copy XPATH" option in the browser.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got stuck on such a stupid thing! Thanks for the help miguelik